# Formatting memoir page notes - how do I eliminate a space?

Tags: memoir, endnotes

I'm trying to format some `memoir` page notes (aka end notes) as a hanging-indent list.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\makepagenote
\renewcommand*{\pagenotesubhead}[3]{}
\renewcommand{\prenoteinnotes}{\begingroup\par\noindent\hangindent 1em}
\renewcommand{\postnoteinnotes}{\par\endgroup}
\renewcommand*{\notenuminnotes}[1]{\normalfont\hbox to 1em{#1}}
\begin{document}
Lalala%
\pagenote{Hopefully antidisestablishmentarianism antimatter extremely difficult justification challenges}

Lelele%
\pagenote{\lipsum[47]}

\printpagenotes
\end{document}
```

My problem is that, due to the way `\printpagenotes` works, I get an extra space inserted between the note number and the note text. Furthermore, there's also some soggy glue here, as shown in the result:

[image]

The blue line shows where I had hoped to set the start of the note text (at 1em in this example), and the red line vs 'Hope' and 'Don' is the evidence for the soggy glue.

I have no idea how to fix this. Can someone help, please?

Comment: Who downvoted this question?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer not me, but if 4 more do, maybe I'll be in with a chance of a reversal badge:-)

Comment: I'd be most grateful if the downvoter could explain, thus helping me and others to do better in future. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Unlikely ;-) This question is not bad at all, in my point of view.

Comment: That odd, I've tags it and will add it to my too list when time permits.

Comment: @daleif Lars, I think it's because the text of the note just "follows on" in the .ent file. Adding a % after the fourth parameter to `\startnoteentry` in the .ent file might well fix it.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough,exactly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\renewcommand\prenotetext{\ignorespaces}
```

---

To spot this, I just added `\tracingall` which says

```
\prenotetext ->
{blank space  }
{the letter H}
```

so defining `\prenotetext` to not be a space fixes it, making it `\ignorespaces` is just "belt and braces".